# Having trouble using nested loops/ accessing data in a list of list

Tags: python

This is the question:
Define a function named list_dic_gen with two parameters. The first parameter will be a list
of strings. The second parameter will be a list whose entries are also lists. You SHOULD
assume each entry in the second parameter will have the same length as the first parameter.
Your list_dic_gen function will use these parameters to create and return a list of
dictionaries. These dictionaries' keys will come from the first parameter and the values will be
from an entry in the second parameter. The key list and the entries in each value list parallel
each other: the entry at index 0 of the first parameter will be associated with the entry at index 0 in each list in the second parameter; the entry at index 1 in the first parameter will be associated with the entry at index 1 in each list in the second parameter; and so on.
The order of the dictionaries in your returned list must parallel the entries in the second
parameter -- the first dictionary's values will be the first entry's data, the second dictionary's
values will be the second entry's data, and so on. Since Python will create a new dictionary
only when a variable is assigned a dictionary literal, the statement assigning a variable to
the empty dictionary MUST be inside the for-loop iterating through the entries of the
second parameter.

As an example, if this were a function call:
list_dic_gen(['One','Two'], [['First','Second']])
the expected return value would be:

[{'One': 'First', 'Two': 'Second'}]

As a second example of this, the function call:
list_dic_gen(['Second'], [['One'],['Third Fourth']])
would be expected to return:

[{'Second': 'One'}, {'Second': 'Third Fourth'}]

Here is my code.

```
def list_dic_gen(lst,lol):
  acc=[]
  accd={}
  a=0
  for l in lol:
    for o in l:
      accd[lst[a]]=l[a]
      acc.append(accd)
      a+=1
    return acc
```

The problem is it prints

```
[{'One': 'First', 'Two': 'Second'}, {'One': 'First', 'Two': 'Second'}]
```

But I just want

```
[{'One': 'First', 'Two': 'Second'}]
```

lol is a list within list and i cant figure out how to loop it like the question ask. If its only 1 list within a list i can get it, but that same code wont work if its 2 list within a list. and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Try to empty your `acct` dictionary at the start of each loop. The dict not being emptied seems to be your issue. Something like:

```py
def list_dic_gen(lst,lol):
  acc=[]
  a=0
  for l in lol:
    accd={}
    for o in l:
      accd[lst[a]]=l[a]
      acc.append(accd)
      a+=1
    return acc
```

Comment: It still has the problem that it prints this ```[{'One': 'First', 'Two': 'Second'}, {'One': 'First', 'Two': 'Second'}]```  Its 2 lists, it should only be 1